# What does "cat foo foo foo does"?

Tags: unix, cat

hey i wana prepare  for various basic commands for unix so for that i need this ans.
what is the output of cat foo foo foo in unix?I m confused  will it display the output of foo file three times or anything else that i may not know?
any help is appreciated?

UPDATE: actually i m not having UNIX installed and i m just preparing for test.I know this question is not to be asked but there is no other means to me except this.and even i have searched for it.

Comment: actually i m not having unix installed in ma pc and i m preparing for test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the manpages (`man cat`).

> cat [-benstuv] [file ...]
>
> The cat utility reads files sequentially [...]

Yes, it will display `foo` three times.

Answer (score 1):

They will be considered as three different files, so you would get three time the content of foo

Answer (score 1):

Display the contents of `foo` three times one after other. Better, read `man cat`

Answer (score 0):

Funny, it looks like nobody noticed that it does more that replicating the contents of file `foo`?
It shows the content of the file `does` directly after three times showing the content of file `foo`!

Technically, `cat` does not look at the file names in the command line, except for reading the files.

That means it **"does not know" that one file is used three times**. What it means is that it does not make use of the information that a file name is repeated. But something like saving the content the first time, and write it out two more times would be invalid anyway - the file could have changed while reading the first time.

### Concatenating the content of four files, that's what it does!

And - that's why `cat` is named `cat` - it is for **concatenating** files!

I mean, that title could really be a nice **trick question** - lots of confusion in few words.